# SQL: Why must I use IN function here instead of an equals sign and OR?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question: Write a query that selects all columns from benn.college_football_players and adds an additional column that displays the player's name if that player is a junior or senior.

My answer:

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
WHEN year = 'JR' OR 'SR' THEN player_name 
ELSE NULL 
END AS highlighted_player
FROM benn.college_football_players
```

Correct Answer:

```
SELECT *,
CASE WHEN year IN ('JR', 'SR') THEN player_name ELSE NULL END AS upperclass_player_name
FROM benn.college_football_players
```

Why does the IN function work here but not an = and OR function?

Comment: The major reason is that your version is not syntactically correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` is a boolean operator, meaning that it works on true/false expressions.  So, this construct would work:

```
year = 'JR' OR year = 'SR'
```

Because it is parsed as:

```
(year = 'JR') OR (year = 'SR')
```

and the two expressions are boolean.  However, this has a string and a boolean expression:

```
(year = 'JR') OR 'SR'
```

so you get an error.

And, `IN` is simpler and clearer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It could work this way:

```
CASE WHEN year = 'JR' OR year = 'SR' THEN ...
```

The `OR` requires that both terms are boolean expressions. But `'SR'` on its own is just a string, not a boolean expression.

This shouldn't be a surprise to anyone with programming experience. In virtually any other programming language (Java, C++, etc.) you would have a similar requirement.

Code syntax is not English.

Answer (score 0):

Change statement from

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN year = 'JR' OR 'SR' ...
```

to :

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN year = 'JR' OR year = 'SR' ...
```